# why after install maven project on windows 7 fond repository empty

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

after installing **maven project** on windows 7 32 bits and link with eclipse IDE , i will fond the folder repository empty 
 why

Comment: repository `/.m2` ? it's normal you have to launch `mvn clean install` to download all the jars of your project

Comment: but if i want download all the jars how do it

Comment: `mvn clean install` will dl all the jars.